# How to obtain the standard deviation of several data sets with multiple measurements within each set?

Tags: standard-deviation, matlab, error

- I have done an experiment and repeated the set of measurements 3 times, totalling 3 data sets.
- In each set of measurements the machine acquired 30 data sets. Meaning that in total I have 90 data arrays (1000 data points per array).
- In other words, I have a 30x1000x3 3D matrix.

**How do I calculate the standard deviation of each of the second quantity so that I can obtain a matrix of 1x1000 of the standard deviations?**

---

I have attempted the following 2 ways:

- averaging all values across the z direction, obtaining a 30x1000 2D matrix, and get the standard deviation across the y-dimension to obtain a 1x1000 matrix with the std values.
- calculate the standard deviation along the z direction, obtaining a 30x1000 2D matrix of std values, and then average these values along the y-dimension to obtain a 1x1000 matrix with the std values.

These have the same results, but I have been told by a colleague that this can be done in a better way that considerably reduces the std values, and that this is the right way of doing it. Any idea of how to?

Comment: Welcome to cv! What the best way is, depends a lot on what you want to do with the std values. So, you measured every point on 3 measurement occasions, and did 30 repetitions each time, as far as I understand. What do you want to describe with the std? the variation between the 30 measurements within one day, or the variation between measurement occasions? It would help a lot if you could give some background.

Comment: p.s.I wonder if I have understood you correctly, but can't see how you got the same results in the two approaches. The std of averages is smaller than the std of original data - did you correct for that? and did you get exactly the same results, or qualitatively?